# Question about the proof of Theorem 23.1 in Matsumura

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a regular local ring, $B$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring, and $\varphi:A \to B$ be a local homomorphism. Suppose that $x$ and $\varphi(x)$ are $A$-regular and $B$-regular respectively, and $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{A/(x)}(A/\mathfrak{m}, B/(\varphi(x)))=0$, i.e., $B/(\varphi(x))$ is flat $A/(x)$-module. How can one shows that $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{A/(x)}(A/\mathfrak{m}, B/(\varphi(x)))=\operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{A}(A/\mathfrak{m}, B)$?

What I tried to do is use the first change of ring theorem in Weibel, Thm 4.3.3. According to it, projective dimension of $B/(\varphi(x))$ as $A$-module is 1, thus $\operatorname{Tor}_{r}^{A}(A/\mathfrak{m}, B/(\varphi(x))=0$ for all $r > 1$. However, I do not know how to proceed it further to get the conclusion. Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is part of the proof of "Miracle Flatness Theorem". I will give a complete proof of this theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $(R,\mathfrak m)\to(S,\mathfrak n)$ be a local homomorphism of Noetherian local rings. If
(i) $R$ is regular,
(ii) $S$ Cohen-Macaulay,
(iii) $\dim S=\dim R +\dim S/\mathfrak mS$.
then $S$ is $R$-flat.

*Proof.* By induction on $\dim R$. If $\dim R=0$, then $R$ is a field and there is nothing to prove. Assume $\dim R>0$. Then, by (iii) we have $\dim S>0$. Let $\mathfrak q_1,\dots,\mathfrak q_r$ be the minimal primes of $S$. Since $S$ is Cohen-Macaulay $\dim S/\mathfrak q_i=\dim S >\dim S/\mathfrak mS$ and this implies $\mathfrak mS\nsubseteq\mathfrak q_i$. It follows that $\mathfrak p_i=\mathfrak q_i\cap R\subsetneq\mathfrak m$. By prime avoidance there exists $x\in\mathfrak m$, $x\notin\mathfrak m^2$ and $x\notin\mathfrak p_i$ for all $i$. In particular, $x\notin\mathfrak q_i$ for all $i$ and therefore $x$ is regular on $S$. This implies that $S/xS$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $\dim S/xS=\dim S-1$. Since $x\in\mathfrak m\setminus\mathfrak m^2$ we can also conclude that $R/xR$ is regular with $\dim R/xR=\dim R-1$. By induction $S/xS$ is $R/xR$-flat and thus $\mathrm{Tor}_1^{R/xR}(R/\mathfrak m,S/xS)=0$.

In order to prove that $S$ is $R$-flat it is enough to show that $\mathrm{Tor}_1^{R}(R/\mathfrak m,S)=0$ (by the local criterion for flatness). In fact, we have $\mathrm{Tor}_i^{R}(R/\mathfrak m,S)=\mathrm{Tor}_i^{R/xR}(R/\mathfrak m,S/xS)$ for all $i\ge1$. First notice that $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(R/xR,S)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$. This follows easily from the fact that $x$ is $R$-regular and $S$-regular. Now let $\mathcal F_{\bullet}$ be a free resolution of $S$ as $R$-module. Since $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(R/xR,S)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$, $R/xR\otimes_R\mathcal F_{\bullet}$ is a free resolution of $S/xS$ as $R/xR$-module. We thus have $$\mathrm{Tor}_i(R/\mathfrak m,S)=H_i(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R\mathcal F_{\bullet})\simeq H_i(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_{R/xR}(R/xR\otimes_R\mathcal F_{\bullet}))=\mathrm{Tor}_i^{R/xR}(R/\mathfrak m,S/xS).$$